# Tcp Socket recv function doesn't work c++

Tags: c++, sockets, tcp, client-server, tcpsocket

I am dealing with problem that after sending data successfully i recv the first response from the client but the second one after he put his details and submit not.
do you have any idea why this happend? 
Here is my code:

```
    sock->listenAndAccept();
    string url="HTTP/1.1 302 Found \r\nContent-Type: text/html; charset=utf8 \r\nContent-        Length:279\r\n\r\n<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><title>Creating an HTML Element</title></head><body><form name=\"input\" action=\"login.html\" method=\"get\">user name: <input type=\"text\" name=\"user\"><br>password: <input type=\"text\" name=\"password\"><input type=\"submit\" value=\"Submit\"></form></body></html>";
    sock->send(url.data(),url.length());
    char buffer[1000];
    sock->recv(buffer, 1000);
    cout<<buffer<<endl;
    sock->recv(buffer, 1000);
    cout<<buffer<<endl;
```

listen and accept function:

```
TCPSocket* TCPSocket::listenAndAccept(){
    int rc = listen(socket_fd, 1);
    if (rc<0){
        return NULL;
    }
    size_t len = sizeof(peerAddr);
    bzero((char *) &peerAddr, sizeof(peerAddr));

    int connect_sock = accept(socket_fd, (struct sockaddr *)&peerAddr,(unsigned int *)&len);
    return new TCPSocket(connect_sock,serverAddr,peerAddr);
}
```

recv function:

```
int TCPSocket::recv(char* buffer, int length){
    return read(socket_fd,buffer,length);
}
```

Comment: What's with the space between `Content-` and `Length:`?

Comment: Also, did you write the client? How do you know the client is sending a response? (I suspect that your client is a web browser, and it is opening a new connection [which is not wrong])

Comment: I'm using the web browser as my client

Comment: how are you sure that the web browser is reusing the connection? (which it's allowed to do, and probably does sometimes, but is not required to do and usually won't)

Comment: i am not sure. how can i make sure it is?

Comment: You can't. That's like asking "How can I make sure that if I order pizza on two different days, they use the same car?". (and the answer is that if you care about which car your pizza comes in, you're doing it wrong)

Comment: I just saw the following answer in google:
"When using HTTP/1.1, by default, the TCP connections are left open for reuse. "

Comment: and if you think i am doing wrong. so what do you think i need to change in my code?

Comment: Yes. The browser is *allowed* to reuse the connection. It doesn't have to, and in practice it won't. Connection reuse is typically for downloading images, scripts, videos, etc... on the page.

Comment: "so what do you think I need to change in my code" - I think you need to understand HTTP works, and then it will be obvious (and you'll probably need to throw out part of it and start over)

Comment: If you're implementing HTTP you need to read and understand and implement the relevant RFCs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Always always always (I can't say that often enough) check the return value of `recv`. `recv` will read *up to* the amount you have requested. If you're certain the amount you've requested is on its way then you must go into a loop around `recv` buffering incoming data until you've received what you expect to receive.

This kind of bug tends to sit there lurking unseen while you test on your local machine using the very fast localhost interface and then surfaces as soon as you start running the client and server on different hosts.

When you move on from your test code to actual code then you must also deal with zero length responses (client closed the socket) and error codes (<0 response).

Finally, please post your client code. There may be bugs there as well.

Comment: There is no client code. my client is a web browser.
and in the first time the return value of the recv is just an accept that the site is up and then its just stuck in the recv function wait for response without moving on

Comment: Are you saying that the browser does read your page and you are able to enter credentials into the page but you do not see the form submission? If that's the case then remember that modern browsers are capable of opening multiple simultaneous connections to a website and using them as they see fit to increase performance. The browser may have given up on your 'site' because it's got a connection pending and hanging in your listen backlog.

Answer (score 1):

TCP is stream oriented protocol. It might be possible that you have read all the messages in first recv. Check the size of received data and see if it matches the expected output.

Comment: No this is not possible.
I debuged the program step by step and put the details of username and password on the site just after the first recv finish. and then   the second recv got nothing and the site just loading and loading

Comment: got nothing= waiting for data and got nothing. he still keep waiting for it

Comment: I am sure there is something to read after you fill 2 fields with data and click on button.

Comment: client needs to send the data inorder to get it read by server. By just filling a buffer which is already send will not help. If possible, post client code.

Comment: my client is web browser

Comment: Then, you can use sniffer such as Wireshark and make sure that client is sending the message.